# Differences between cProfile and profile —why no profile.Profile.enable() method?

Tags: python

In both Python 2.7 and Python 3.6, I find that this works:

```
from cProfile import Profile; p = Profile(); p.enable()
```

...whereas this raises an exception:

```
from profile import Profile; p = Profile(); p.enable()

# -->  AttributeError: 'Profile' object has no attribute 'enable'
```

This surprises me, because I thought (and the official docs for both [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#module-cProfile) and [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#module-cProfile) state) that the two modules were supposed to provide identical programmer's interfaces:

> Both the `profile` and `cProfile` modules provide the following functions:
>
> ...
>
> `class profile.Profile(timer=None, timeunit=0.0, subcalls=True, builtins=True)`
>
> ...
>
> `enable()`
>
> Start collecting profile data.

What am I missing?   And what *is* the correct way to use a `profile.Profile()` instance?

Comment: You're not missing anything. I, too, have found this to be the case...and have verified it by looking at the CPython source code. However I don't know "why" it like this, just that it is in fact the way things are written.

Comment: @martineau +1 What would be the correct way to use profile.Profile() -- verified behavior also exists on Python 3.7 and 3.8

Comment: @jon: The current Python 3.x documentation for the [`Profile.enable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#profile.Profile.enable) method says it's only available in `cProfile` which implies you would have to use one of `profile.Profile`'s `run*()` methods instead. Here's some [examples](https://pymotw.com/3/profile/index.html#module-profile).

Comment: Yep, I discovered that after using inspect.getmembers() on profile and found the run() methods present. I'll post an answer with the info.

Comment: @jon: FYI, when replying to comment not made by the OP, you need to add the user's name prefixed with an `@` so they will be notified you've done it. I found out you had in this case strictly by luck (because sometimes I check back to see what, if any, response there might have been from one I recently made myself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) and newer documentation, they have fixed this to specify that `enable()` and `disable()` are only available with `cProfile`. With `profile.Profile`, you need to use the `run()` invocation as opposed to `enable()` and `disable()`. Below are samples for each:

**cProfile.Profile:**

```
# cProfile.Profile -- control with enable() and disable()
from datetime import datetime
import cProfile, pstats, io
sortby = 'cumulative'
pr1 = cProfile.Profile(lambda: int(datetime.now().timestamp()*1000000), 0.000001)
pr1.enable()
list(x for x in range(int(10*10*10*10/10*10+10)))
pr1.disable()
s1 = io.StringIO()
ps1 = pstats.Stats(pr1, stream=s1).sort_stats(sortby)
ps1.print_stats()
print(s1.getvalue())
```

**profile.Profile:**

```
# profile.Profile -- control with run()
from datetime import datetime
import profile, pstats, io
sortby = 'cumulative'
pr2 = profile.Profile(datetime.now().timestamp, 0.000001)
pr2.run('list(x for x in range(int(10*10*10*10/10*10+10)))')
s2 = io.StringIO()
ps2 = pstats.Stats(pr2, stream=s2).sort_stats(sortby)
ps2.print_stats()
print(s2.getvalue())
```

### Here are some behavioral differences I observed between the two forms:

- `cProfile` will push profiled functions' output to stdout, whereas `profile` will not.
- The final report's `filename:lineno(function)` column will have slightly different output. `cProfile` generally will display built-in functions more readably.

  - In the example I provided here, however, the passed in function is actually identifiable in `profile`'s output and *not* in `cProfile`'s -- but if using a named function, it is identifiable in *both* profilers' output (although the passed in *arguments* to the function are only visible from `profile`'s output).
- Running identical functions thru both `cProfile` and `profile` provides slightly different results. It seems `cProfile` generates about two less function calls generally, and will provide more efficient times for the same function.
- Using the profilers' optional custom `timer` and `timeunit` parameters can offer the benefit of gaining *microsecond* precision vs the default *millisecond* precision. However, it seems that attempting to use these comes with some caveats:

  - `cProfile`'s timeunit function requires an integer, whereas `profile` expects  a floating point number. This means you can't use `datetime.now().timestamp()` directly with `cProfile`, but must rather wrap it in a lambda to convert it to a full integer first.
  - Additionally, for some reason `profile` seems to not work correctly with `datetime.now().timestamp()` even though that's in the format it's expecting. It will print out negative time values -- I show this below. Switching to the lambda form to convert it to integer doesn't help, as `profile` expects the floating point number.
- Below is the output of `profile.Profile` with the `datetime.now().timestamp()` timer for microsecond provision.

  ```
   print(s2.getvalue())
         10015 function calls in -0.020 seconds`

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        0    0.000             0.000          profile:0(profiler)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(setprofile)
    10011   -0.010   -0.000   -0.010   -0.000 <string>:1(<genexpr>)
        1   -0.010   -0.010   -0.020   -0.020 <string>:1(<module>)
        1   -0.000   -0.000   -0.020   -0.020 :0(exec)
        1   -0.000   -0.000   -0.020   -0.020 profile:0(list(x for x in range(int(10*10*10*10/10*10+10))))
  ```
- However, this problem can be fixed by providing a custom timer function (which can even wrap around `datetime.now()` to provide the exact same output format as `datetime.now().timestamp()`), for reasons I can't explain.

e.g. If we define:

```
def timenow():
   now = datetime.now()
   return (((now.year-1970) * 31557600) + (now.month * 2629800) + 
           (now.day * 86400) + (now.hour * 3600) + (now.minute * 60) +
           now.second + (now.microsecond * 0.000001))
```

We can now use `pr2 = profile.Profile(timenow, 0.000001)`, and this will output the following (sane) report:

```
>>> print(s2.getvalue())
         10015 function calls in 0.041 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.006    0.006    0.041    0.041 profile:0(list(x for x in range(int(10*10*10*10/10*10+10))))
        1    0.000    0.000    0.035    0.035 :0(exec)
        1    0.017    0.017    0.035    0.035 <string>:1(<module>)
    10011    0.018    0.000    0.018    0.000 <string>:1(<genexpr>)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 :0(setprofile)
        0    0.000             0.000          profile:0(profiler)
```

Comparing with the output of `cProfile` (using the custom lambda timer as defined above), we have:

```
>>> print(s1.getvalue())
         10013 function calls in 0.031 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    10011    0.031    0.000    0.031    0.000 <stdin>:1(<genexpr>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <stdin>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

As to why our custom timer function gives sensible results and `datetime.now().timestamp()` does not with `profile`, first it must be noted that `timenow` doesn't provide timings to `datetime.now().timestamp()`. Although it provides close to epoch time, it is off by small amount (nothing that should affect normal profile runs as the deltas will be identical on the same system). The manual conversion used in `timenow` also surely isn't as efficient as in `datetime.now().timestamp()`. I can only speculate that the latter is *too efficient* and that somehow the `profile` source code doesn't properly measure as a result.

### TL;DR

Use `cProfile` unless you have a specific reason not to. The official Python docs  also state that the recommended module is `cProfile`. Although no specific justification is provided, the doc seems to imply that `cProfile` might be better behaved and suitable for most users' purposes (even though it is a slightly more verbose syntax).